# my code doesn't execute after first command?

Tags: c, shell, systems-programming

INPUT

```
echo "/bin/ls
     /bin/ls
/bin/ls
   /bin/ls     " | ./hsh
```

OUTPUT

Only first /bin/ls

I want to know why it doesn't execute other commands?
I used strtok to split string input as i understand echo gives input as string seperated by \n.

I have tried to execute after tokenizing each delimiter, it also gave same output

```
#include "O_X.h"

/**
 * main - program
 * Return: 0 on success, -1 on fail
 */
char **environ;

int main(void)
{
    char *buff = NULL, *token = NULL;
    int size = 1, kiddo = 0, stat = 0;
    char *arg[] = {"" ,NULL};
    size_t len = 33;
    while (1)
    {
        size = getline(&buff, &len, stdin);
        if (size == -1)
        {
            free(buff);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (buff == NULL)
            free(buff);
/*      else if (buff[size - 1] == '\n')
            buff[size - 1] = '\0';*/

        token = strtok(buff, "\n");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }


        kiddo = fork();
        if (kiddo == -1)
            printf("Process error!\n");
        if (kiddo == 0)
        {
            if (buff[0] != '/')
              buff++;
                execve(buff, arg, environ);
            return (0);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&stat);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but `buff` is a single char pointer; you never allocate any memory, and thus will not be able to `free` it either.

Comment: The second line begins with a space, so `if (buff[0] != '/') return (0);` causes your child process to exit with status 0 (success).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from `buff` that can contain extra spaces before or after the program you want to run.

`strtok` can be used to remove the characters you don't want:

```c
while (1)
{
    size = getline(&buff, &len, stdin);
    if (size <1)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    // extract first sequence of non-spaces characters for buff
    token = strtok(buff, " \t\n");

    if(*token == 0) {
        // empty line, go next line
        continue;
    }

    kiddo = fork();
    if (kiddo == -1)
        printf("Process error!\n");
    if (kiddo == 0)
    {

        printf("token(child): '%s'\n", token);
        // here you can call "arg[xx] = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");" to get the arguments
        execve(token, arg, environ);
        printf("execution of '%s' failed\n", token);
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&stat);
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case my program have to work like shell, that is why i don't want to check every command but which starts by /

Comment: but thanks for the solution, i will check similar approach

Comment: "hat is why i don't want to check every command but which starts by /" Ok, so what do you want to test when you write `if (buff[0] != '/')`?

Comment: To check is it starts with / character or anything else, if it is anything else move to the next pointer. I have changed code

Comment: but as you mentioned buff++ just changes character? How i can move to the next token

Comment: Ok, I understand you problem now. In the example you gave, you have only one token by line. lines are separated by `getline` and `strtok(...'\n')` If you want to remove all spaces from line, you can use `strtok(..." \t\n")`
I updated my answer according to your precisions